# The same Python Telethon script works differently on two machines

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have a simple script that downloads every image file that is being sent in specific Telegram group:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(groups_list))
async def new_message(event):
   if event.photo:
    path= await event.download_media('PATH')
```

When I run this script on my machine it works fine and downloads every image. But when I run it on VPS it doesn't collect everything. Ignores a lot of messages and groups.
What can be the problem?

Comment: You should enable `logging`. In addition to that, Telegram will only send updates to recently-used sessions, so if you have a lot active some may see slow-downs or even not receive any update.

Comment: This was just a part of the whole script. The script uses: 'import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname) 5s/%(asctime)s] %(name)s: %(message)s', level=logging.WARNING)'  The thing is that on my VM it works perfectly well, but on VPS it doesn't... While the script is identical...